# making a game in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

[I want to make the game like the one here](http://www.mousebreaker.com/games/sportsheadsfootball/playgame)

i made a `JFrame` and background and the players but i cant move the players please help me !
this is my source : they are 3 clases in 1 package.
is the main class true ?! 
this my uni project and i am confused ........

```
package sportshead;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;

public class screen extends JFrame{
     private Image back;
     private Image player1;
     private Image player2;
     private Image goal1;
     private Image goal2;
     private Image ball;

    Player1 p = new Player1();

public screen(){
    setTitle("The title");
    setSize(1500, 800);
    setLocation(0,0);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
     }
public void loadPics(){
        player1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\player1.png").getImage();
        player2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\player2.png").getImage();
        goal1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\goal1.png").getImage();
        goal2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\goal2.png").getImage();
        ball = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\ball.png").getImage();
        back = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\Background.jpg").getImage();
        repaint();
       }
public void paint(Graphics g){
         g.drawImage(back, 0, 0, null);
         p.paint(g);
         g.drawImage(player2, -400, 200, null);
         g.drawImage(goal1, 400, 145, null);
         g.drawImage(goal2, -500, 140, null);
         g.drawImage(ball, -20, -200, null);
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         g.drawLine(0, 603, 1400, 603);
     }
}


package sportshead;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage;

public class Player1 extends JFrame {

    private Image image;
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;
    public int yMove =200;  
    public int xMove = 200;   

public Player1(){
         image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Test\\player1.png").getImage();
         addKeyListener( new KeyList());
       }

public void paint(Graphics g) {  
        g.drawImage(image, xMove, yMove, this);  
    } 
public void moveLeft() {  
        x = xMove--;  
    }  

public void moveRight() {  
        y = xMove++;  
    }  
public void moveReset(int value) {  
        xMove = value;  
    }

    // inner class
private class KeyList extends KeyAdapter {  
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {  
            if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){  
                moveLeft();  
            }  
            if (k.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){  
                moveRight();  
            }  
        }  
    } 
}

package sportshead;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;

public class Main extends JFrame{

     public static void main(String [] args){

          int i =0;

          screen s = new screen();
          s.loadPics();
          Player1  p = new Player1();
          for(i=0;i<50;i+=5){
            p.xMove+=i;
            p.yMove+=i;
            p.repaint();
            s.loadPics();
        }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? e.g. do you receive any key-events? have you added printouts so you see that you handle the events as you want?

Comment: Start with the basics.  [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), then move onto some more difficult tasks, [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).  You don't want to be painting to top level containers like `JFrame`, but instead use something like `JPanel`

Comment: Swing is not really fun to develop video games, I advice you to look for another library like [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [libGDX](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)

Comment: You have 3 classes, all extending JFrame.  It's obvious that you don't understand Swing or how to put a Swing GUI together.  Read this article, Sudoku Solver Swing GUI, to see how to put together a Swing GUI.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont get the for loop in main (like 1 nanosec runtime?) but anyway. You need a proper game loop at first. After changing the position of player you have to rerender the frame. Search for writing gameloops, my suggestion. And maybe also search for DoubleBufferStrategys, so you get a fluid rendering.

**[Example](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0)**

Comment: for loop is for testing !    i wanted to see that the image player1 move or not and i got it doesnt move !

Answer (score 0):

For game application use Timer service for animation and graphics. **[Read the Java Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)**

For rich animation game. Use JavaFX.